# One-tailed $F$-test with multiple restrictions

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, f-test, one-tailed-test

I have a regression, say $Y=a+bX_1+cX_2+e$.

I know how to do the standard $F$-test for $b=c=0$. However, in my case, both coefficients $b$ and $c$ should be positive. So is there a way to test if $b>0$ AND $c>0$? This would be a one-tailed $F$-test with two restrictions.

Comment: The first thing you mention is a null; presumably you mean against an alternative of at least one not being 0. Is the second thing mean to be an alternative hypothesis rather than a null?

Comment: I want to test the null $b>0$ AND $c>0 $

Comment: A composite null that doesn't include its boundary? I don't think that's going to work even for one variable.

Comment: Interesting question. I encountered multiple one-sided restrictions before in an econometrics class, and if I remember correctly it was generally impossible to test for.

Comment: Related: [One-tailed F-test with one restriction](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180478/one-tailed-f-test-with-one-restriction).